# Get all values in the row `java.sql.ResultSet` in one go

Tags: java, ojdbc

Using the `java.sql.ResultSet` Class, I want to get all the cells in a row as an Object List, or Object array, and postpone the processing/fetching of each cell, for performance concerns. The following method:

```
Object obj = resultSet.getObject(i);
```

should be called `columnCount` number of times.

What is the fastest way? / Why is a seemingly obvious functionality missing?

Comment: How about just using a loop?

Comment: And how exactly do you propose to avoid "fetching"? This smells like a massively premature optimization.

Comment: Wouldn't a Obj[] getAllObjects() reduce number of function calls? 'column' fold? Why is it untimely for thinking about speed?

Comment: Maybe because no one wants an array of Object where they have to type cast every element

Comment: In my usecase, which I think is not too specific, I load the data and some metadata, ship it to some frontend module, possibly in the future, on a separate machine. The frontend will take care of the casting and processing further. While / Because my backend would be my bottleneck. Therefore it would have been nice to have the function. I hope I am not raising eyebrows with my design :)

Comment: `get all the cells in a row' and 'postpone the processing/fetching of each cell` are mutually contradictory.

Answer (score 3):

I think this might do what you want. It should return all the columns values of the `ResultSet` current row.

```
List<Object> getValues(ResultSet resultSet) {
   ResultSetMetaData metadata = resultSet.getMetadata();
   int numberOfCols = metadata.getColumnCount();

   List<Object> values = new ArrayList<>();

   for(i=1; i <= numberOfCols; i ++) {
      values.add(resultSet.getObject(i));
   }

   return values;
}
```

Comment: index start from 1?

Comment: @jacky Yes, you're right!